# SAS EG LIKE operator on numeric value

Tags: sql, sas

Does SAS EG have an operator similar to LIKE that works on numeric instead of characters.
Like this statement:

```
WHERE t1.REGNSKKD_R LIKE '302%';
```

Comment: What do you expect as a result? Do you want to find a certain pattern like: any number that begins with 302 (regardless of the dimension of the number) or are you looking for a range: between 30200 and 30299? In the first case you can transform your number to a character and then use LIKE in proc-sql or a SAS character function in either proc-sql or a data-step, in the latter case you can of course use a numeric expression.

Comment: Myy case is the your first example so the number will always have the same length like 30210110. But there must be an easier way than changing it to a character.

What would the numeric expression be for the latter case?

Comment: I don't think there is a totally numeric way that more efficient than `cats(num) like '302%'`.

Comment: @whymath does cats(num) change it to a character?

Comment: @Christoffer Yes. `cat()` series function will convert numeric input into their character type, quietly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the column REGNSKKD_R has a fixed length of 8 digits then the numeric solution to your problem is the following:

```
WHERE t1.REGNSKKD_R between 30200000 and 30299999
```